# How can I read PostgreSQL Table partitions with AWS Glue Crawler?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

My Crawler is not able to read the RDS partitioned table properly when partitions are created in Postgresql 11.

Example of partition DDL is

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    ID int8 NULL,
    effectivetodate date NULL,
) PARTITION BY RANGE(effectivetodate);
```

Partitions:

```
CREATE TABLE book_historical PARTITION OF portfolio for VALUES FROM ('1000-12-31') TO ('2019-12-31');
CREATE TABLE book_current PARTITION OF portfolio DEFAULT;
```

The observation is that two tables:

- book_historical
- book_current

are created by Crawler but the main table

- book

is not there.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please use proper formatting for your question so that others can understand it and answer it. I suggest you to read asking [guidelines of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Abhishek does it look better?

Comment: yes! Someone will answer your question soon...

Answer (score 0):

INstead of using range just pass the column name for partitioning and crawler will dynamically partition based on your column

```
CREATE TABLE book (
    ID int8 NULL,
    effectivetodate date NULL,
) PARTITION BY effectivetodate;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Shubham. I am working in Postgresql 11.6 and partition by field directly does not work in that. We can do partition by List, range etc.

Comment: I thought you are talking about Glue crawlers

Comment: Yes, I was talking about crawler, but we need to create a partition in PostgreSQL before crawler can crawl the partitions. So in my code, I partition the table with Date Range. The crawler is not able to crawl the main table but it was able to read partitioned tables as independent tables.

Comment: There is an option for grouping the data to recognize partition, have you selected that?